# Configure Apache Shiro Permissions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, shiro

Here is the thing:
I want to have users with roles like this:

Table users:
id|username|role_id

Table roles:
id|name|add_users|add_customers|configure_mail|...|...|...

The permissions are type binary, when the user can perform the action It has a 1 or It has a 0 otherwise.

In my shiro.ini I have the queries:

```
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select name from roles where id = (select role_id FROM users WHERE username = ?)
```

Is there a way to do that?.
I have searched for days now. I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got It!!.
Thanks to dev, he really helped me to solve this, here is the solution (shiro.ini)

```
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select id from roles where id = (select role_id FROM users WHERE username = ?)
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT name FROM permissions WHERE  UPPER(role_id)=UPPER(?)
```

I hope It will help someone in the future and thanks for your help @dev

Answer (score 2):

Dont you tink its better to store permission in another table so as you have scope to modify and enhance further like

```
Table users: id|username|role_id

Table roles: id|name

Table permission: permission|role

now in permission table
customer:add,04   -- 04 is role
mail:configure,04
.....
```

so in shiro ini

```
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT permid FROM apppermissions WHERE  UPPER(roleid)=UPPER(?)
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
```

Comment: Hello dev. I did the following:
**Table users: id|username|role_id**
**Table roles: id|name**
**Table permissions: id|name|role_id**

And the apache shiro.ini:
**jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password from users where username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select name from roles where id = (select role_id FROM users WHERE username = ?)
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT name FROM permissions WHERE UPPER(role_id)=UPPER(?)**

It doesn`t work, when I do: **System.out.println(currentUser.isPermitted("customer:add"));**
It shows false, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: It should work  check if u have this in shiro.ini jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true

Comment: It totally works now !!!!!, thank you very much...I really appreciate what you did :D